# appedChild() overwriting divs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array with a nested array that will add divs to the DOM in a loop from the items in the array. When it goes into the nested loop it keeps overwriting the previous div with the last item in the nested array. I cant't figure out why this is happening.

Here is my code:

```
let beans = ["1", "2", "3", ["4", "5", "6"]];

//Loop over the beans array
for (var i = 0; i < beans.length; i++) {

    // create div elements


    // check to see if it is string 
    if (typeof beans[i] === 'string') {
        let divs = document.createElement('div');
        divs.textContent = beans[i];
        document.body.appendChild(divs);

        // console.log(beans[i]);
    } else {
        let divs = document.createElement('div');
        divs.textContent = "These are the array items:";
        document.body.appendChild(divs);
        for (var j = 0; j < beans[i].length; j++) {

            divs.textContent = beans[i][j];
            document.body.appendChild(divs);
            console.log(i + " " + j + " " + beans[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

what i end up getting is 4 divs:
1
2
3
6

so the divs in the nested array overwrite themselves.

I am relatively new to JS and would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` only creates one new element - notice that it calls `document.createElement('div')` exactly once, *before* the loop? You then overwrite that div's content and call `document.body.appendChild(divs)`, but `.appendChild()` doesn't create additional copies, it *moves* existing elements.

You need to add another call to `document.createElement('div')` inside the `for` loop in the `else`.

```js
let beans = ["1", "2", "3", ["4", "5", "6"]];

//Loop over the beans array
for (var i = 0; i < beans.length; i++) {
    // create div elements
    // check to see if it is string 
    if (typeof beans[i] === 'string') {
        let divs = document.createElement('div');
        divs.textContent = beans[i];
        document.body.appendChild(divs);
    } else {
        let divs = document.createElement('div');
        divs.textContent = "These are the array items:";
        document.body.appendChild(divs);
        for (var j = 0; j < beans[i].length; j++) {
            divs = document.createElement('div');        // <--- ADD THIS
            divs.textContent = beans[i][j];
            document.body.appendChild(divs);
            console.log(i + " " + j + " " + beans[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked! I had tried originally to use the variable 'divs' but that did not work. writing it out how you explained worked perfect. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It didn't necessarily need to be the *same* variable as the one used to add "These are the array items", but it is fine to reuse the same one for this case.